# How to use ggplot to align my two labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot plot with two labels. I want to add both labels onto my plot, aligned vertically. I want my second label drawn below the first label, but they should not overlap.

So if I want to draw the first label at (20,90), where should the second label go? Obviously, it depends on the y-axis of the data set and the height required for the first label.

[image]

**Q:** The coordinates are hard-coded (see my script) and won't work for a new data set. I want to come up with a way such that the two labels are always aligned vertically for **any** data set and scaling. My potential solutions are:

1. Create a single label showing two lines, something like `Line1\nLine2`
2. Use a layout algorithm to force the alignment, like `tableGrob` from the `gridExtra` package.

I don't know how to make **1** works. In **2**, I'm not sure how to make `tableGrob` works with individual labels. What's the easiest solution?

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x=c(1:100), y=x+rnorm(100))

p <- ggplot(data=data, aes_string(x='data$x', y='data$y')) + geom_point()

str1 <- "italic(y) == \"1.7\" + \"1\" * italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"0.91\""
str2 <- "italic(y) == \"9.7\" + \"1\" * italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"9.91\""

above <- annotate("text",
              label=str1,
              x=20,
              y=90,
              parse=TRUE)
below <- annotate("text",
              label=str2,
              x=20,
              y=83,
              parse=TRUE)

p <- p + above
p <- p + below

print(p)
```

Comment: it's not relevant here, but `aes_string(x='data$x', y='data$y')` is a bad idea. Use `aes(x=x, y=y)` instead

Comment: @baptiste Thanks. But my top priority is now position the labels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `atop` to make single label out of the two labels, stacked one atop the other:

```
str3 = 'atop(italic(y) == \"1.7\" + \"1\" * italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"0.91\",
    italic(y) == \"9.7\" + \"1\" * italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"9.91\")'

p + annotate("text",
               label=str3,
               x=20,
               y=90,
               parse=TRUE)
```

[image]

You do still need to enter the coordinates for the single label.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this,

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

table_label <- function(label, params=list())  {

  params <- modifyList(list(hjust=0, x=0), params)

  mytheme <- ttheme_minimal(padding=unit(c(1, 1), "mm"),core = list(fg_params = params), parse=TRUE)
  disect <- strsplit(label, "\\n")[[1]]
  m <- as.matrix(disect)
  tableGrob(m, theme=mytheme)

}

txt <- 'italic(y) == 1.7 + 1 * italic(x) * "," ~~italic(r)^2 ~ "=" ~ 0.91\n
        italic(y) == 9.7 + 1 * italic(x) * "," ~~italic(r)^2 ~ "=" ~ 9.91'


library(ggplot2)

qplot(1:10,1:10) +
  annotation_custom(table_label(txt), xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=7.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Do I know exactly how much width to give to the labels? `annotation_custom` requires `x_min` and `x_max`, and it's unclear what exactly the width I should give to.

Comment: you could give the same value of xmin and xmax in this case, but the table will be centred to that position (and bleed out, it won't be cropped). If you wanted left/right justification it might get a bit trickier (you'd have to wrap the thing in a gTree IIRC)

Answer (score 2):

Try the package `cowplot` which gives you the function `draw_label` which lets you add layers with relative positioning:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

data <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = (1:100) + rnorm(100))

p <- ggplot(data = data, 
            aes(x = x, 
                y = y)) + 
  geom_point()

ggdraw(p) + 
  draw_label(expression(paste(italic(y) == 1.7 + 1 * italic(x), 
                              ", ", 
                              italic(r)^2 == 0.91)), 
             .2, .9) +
  draw_label(expression(paste(italic(y) == 9.7 + 1 * italic(x), 
                              ", ", 
                              italic(r)^2 == 9.91)),
             .2, .83)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the solution requires the y-coordinate of the second label be specified, which is really what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: It's a relative coordinate though, so it doesn't depend on your actual y range.